Move a string from a filename to the end of the filename in Python
If I have documents labeled:
2023_FamilyDrama.pdf
2024_FamilyDrama.pdf
2022-beachpics.pdf

I would like them to be
FamilyDrama_2023.pdf
FamilyDrama_2024.pdf
beachpics_2022.pdf

So far, I know how to remove a string from the beginning of the filename, but do not know how to save it and append it to the end of the string.
import os
for root, dir, fname in os.walk(PATH):
    for f in fname:
        os.chdir(root)
        if f.startswith('2024_'):
            os.rename(f, f.replace('2024_', ''))


Related: Extracting extension from filename

do you have other files in this directory you do not want to change?

For the given filename structure of <year><separator><string>.<extension> and keeping it simple
for n in ["2023_FamilyDrama.pdf", "2024_FamilyDrama.pdf", "2022-beachpics.pdf", "1901_some_other_name.jpg"]:
    name, ext = n.split('.')
    new_name = f"{name[5:]}_{name[:4]}.{ext}"
    print(new_name)

Result
FamilyDrama_2023.pdf
FamilyDrama_2024.pdf
beachpics_2022.pdf
some_other_name_1901.jpg

To rename files
bname = os.path.basename(f)
name, ext = bname.split('.')
new_name = f"{name[5:]}_{name[:4]}.{ext}"
os.rename(f, f.replace(bname, new_name))


For a case where the filename contains more than one ., you may wish to use n.rsplit('.', 1)

this works to change the names of the items in the list, but I want to change the names of the files in my local drive.

@JodeCharger100 added some code (not tested)

This solution uses parse instead of regular expressions.
from parse import parse

fnames = [
    "2023_FamilyDrama.pdf",
    "2024_FamilyDrama.pdf",
    "2022-beachpics.pdf"
    ]

for file_name in fnames:
    year,sep,name,ext = parse("{:d}{}{:l}.{}", file_name)
    print(f"{name}_{year}.{ext}")

# Output:
#   FamilyDrama_2023.pdf
#   FamilyDrama_2024.pdf
#   beachpics_2022.pdf

The statement parse("{:d}{}{:l}.{}", file_name) searches for:

{:d} A number (in your case, the year)
{} Any number of characters up until the beginning of the next matching rule. In your case, either a - or _.
{:l} Any number of letters until the beginning of the next matching rule.
. A period
{} Everything remaining until the end of the string.

The output type from parse() is parse.Result, but I unpacked it like a tuple in this example.
You can rename or move the file however you prefer. I like pathlib
from pathlib import Path
from parse import parse

# The directory containing the files. 
in_dir = Path(r"C:/mystuff/my_pdfs") # Absolute path. Also look into `Path().resolve()`

# Create a list of all PDFs in the directory
# The initial code snippet had the file names hard-coded as a list of strings.
# This creates a list of `Path` objects, so you get just the name of `f` by calling `f.name`
files = [f for f in in_dir.iterdir() if f.name.find(".pdf") > -1]

# Rename each file, one at a time.
for f in files:
    # Extract the subtrings
    year,sep,name,ext = parse("{:d}{}{:l}.{}", f.name)

    # Rearrange them
    new_name = f"{name}_{year}.{ext}"

    # Print friendly message for this example
    print(f"renaming {f.name} to {new_name}")

    # Rename the file
    f.rename(new_name)

# Output
#   renaming 2022-beachpics.pdf to beachpics_2022.pdf
#   renaming 2023_FamilyDrama.pdf to FamilyDrama_2023.pdf
#   renaming 2024_FamilyDrama.pdf to FamilyDrama_2024.pdf

It doesn't matter for your example input, but I should note that {:d} will drop leading zeroes. You can use most format specifications as well. Also see the format examples.
>>> from parse import parse
>>> foo = "0123_abc.pdf"
>>> parse("{0:04}{}{:l}.{}", foo)
<Result ('0123', '_', 'abc', 'pdf') {}>

Alternatively, you can wipe out the hyphens (since you plan to do that anyway). That allows you to hard-code the _ separator and then treat everything as straight format-less {}.
>>> bar = "0123-abc.pdf"
>>> parse("{}_{}.{}", bar.replace("-","_"))
<Result ('0123', 'abc', 'pdf') {}>

Edit: More complicated file names.
The file names in the question all followed the template [year][separator][letters].[extension], so that's why I chose the {:l} pattern. If instead, you have a filename like 2022-workplace-picture-site-report.pdf, then you need a rule for the template [year][one character of anything][any number of anything].[extension]
>>> from parse import parse
>>> fname = "2022-workplace-picture-site-report.pdf"
>>> parse("{:d}{}{}.{}", fname)
<Result (2022, '-', 'workplace-picture-site-report', 'pdf') {}>


your solution is deleting all strings (words) in the textfile and only keeping one word. For example, one of my documents labeled "2022-workplace-picture-site-report.pdf" got renamed to just "report_2022.pdf", while I wanted "workplace-picture-site-report_2022.pdf"

should I edit the question to reflect that?

@JodeCharger100 Ah, well, yeah. That filename pattern doesn't match any of the examples from the question. I'll update with another example. And yeah, you should probably edit the question to include the full range of valid inputs that you're expecting.

Building on the solution by LMC
for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk('PATH'):
    for f in fnames:
        name, ext = f.split('.', 1)
        print(name)
        new_name = f"{name[5:]}_{name[:4]}.{ext}"
        print(new_name)
        os.rename(f, new_name)


Use a regular expression to match the source file(s) you're interested in.
Use pathlib.Path to handle the initial directory search and renaming.
Then it's as simple as:
import re
from pathlib import Path

# the directory you want to search
PATH = Path(".") 
# 4 digits, either hyphen or underscore, an arbitrary sequence ending with .pdf
PATTERN = re.compile(r"^(\d{4})[-_](.+)\.pdf$")

for file in PATH.glob("*.pdf"):
    if m := PATTERN.match(file.name):
        new_name = PATH / "{1}_{0}.pdf".format(*m.groups())
        file.rename(new_name)


SOLUTION 1
A possible solution, which uses:

StringIO to convert the string text into a file-like object, allowing it to be read as a CSV.

read_csv to read the file-like object into a dataframe.

str.split to divide the filenames into components based on underscores, hyphens, or periods.

map to apply a lambda function that rearranges these components into a new format, combining the second and first parts with an underscore and appending the file extension.


import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

text = """
filenames
2023_FamilyDrama.pdf
2024_FamilyDrama.pdf
2022-beachpics.pdf
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))

df['filenames'].str.split(r'_|-|\.').map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}.{x[2]}')


SOLUTION 2
Another possible solution, whose steps are:

First, it uses the re.match function to match each filename in the filenames list against a regular expression pattern. The pattern captures the year, the main part of the name, and the file extension.

If a match is found, it assigns the match object to x using the walrus operator (:=).

Then, it rearranges the captured groups to form a new filename in the format main_part_year.extension.

This process is applied to each filename in the list using a list comprehension, but only includes filenames that match the pattern.


import re

filenames = ['2023_FamilyDrama.pdf', '2024_FamilyDrama.pdf', '2022-beachpics.pdf']
[f"{x[2]}_{x[1]}.{x[3]}" for f in filenames if 
 (x := re.match(r'(\d{4})[_-](.*)\.(.*)', f))]


Output:
0    FamilyDrama_2023.pdf
1    FamilyDrama_2024.pdf
2      beachpics_2022.pdf
Name: filenames, dtype: object


Pandas seems like overkill here. If you're using it because OP tagged the question [tag:pandas], I removed the tag because it seemed to be in error. My best guess is OP tried tagging something like "pd", the start of "PDF", and got the Pandas tag somehow.

Why are you using StringIO and read_csv instead of using OP's code to build a list? And why are you bothering using a DataFrame with one column instead of just a Series?

Yes, @wjandrea, the question was placed in the tag pandas forum. However, pandas, specifically my approach, simplifies the regex, which may be helpful to the OP.

Yes, I could create a series, @wjandrea, but I think the way I used is more straightforward than creating a series from a list. Anyway, those are subjective questions, as strictly related with the own programmer style.

FWIW, another option is .str.replace() using a regex like in Chris's and Art's answers.

Yes, @wjandrea, I knew I could also have used str.replace, but again I like more the str.split approach. I could have even used read.csv to split the columns, instead of str.split!

How is it more straightforward? To get from OP's code to a CSV-like string, you need to join a list-like on newlines, so why not just go straight from the list-like to a Series?

You may want to propose that alternative yourself, given the fact that you do not like my way. Thanks, @wjandrea!

Thanks for the downvote! ;-)

I didn't downvote. Your answer is still useful even if it's overcomplicated IMO.

I do not really care about downvotes, but it is nice to know that you have not downvoted, @wjandrea. Meanwhile, I have added a second solution, which does not use pandas -- it uses a list instead.

As your sting format is:
(digits)(- or _)(letters).(letters)
So, regex pattern should be:
([0-9]+)[_-]([a-z]+)(\.[a-z]+)
i.e  (group_01)[-_](group_02)(group_03)
Now swap the group_02 & group_01

So, simple way to do this:
import re

fList = ["2023_FamilyDrama.pdf",
         "2024_FamilyDrama.pdf", 
         "2022-beachpics.pdf"]

for x in fList :
    print(re.sub(r'([0-9]+)[_-]([a-z]+)(\.[a-z]+)', r'\2_\1\3', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

Alternative solution:
result = [re.sub(r'([a-z0-9]+)[_-]([a-z0-9]+)(\.[a-z]+)', r'\2_\1\3', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE) for x in fList]

print(result)

Alternative regex:
re.sub(r'([a-z0-9]+)[_-]([a-z0-9]+)(\.[a-z]+)', r'\2_\1\3', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

Link: https://www.programiz.com/online-compiler/5K0SNWxLd1idy

Note that the OP has not stated as a requirement that the descriptor or extension only contain letters.

thatswhy add alternative regex: r'([a-z0-9]+)[_-]([a-z0-9]+)(\.[a-z]+)', r'\2_\1\3'

you need to modify your existing script to extract the year from the start of the filename, remove it, and then append it to the end of the filename.
Here's how you can modify your script:
import os
Define the path where your files are stored
PATH = 'your_directory_path_here'
Walk through the directory
for root, dir, fname in os.walk(PATH):
for f in fname:
# Change the working directory to the current folder
os.chdir(root)
    # Check if the filename contains a year at the beginning (e.g., 2024_)
    parts = f.split('_', 1)  # Split at the first underscore
    if len(parts) > 1:
        # Extract the year part from the filename
        year = parts[0]
        name = parts[1]

        # Form the new filename
        new_name = f"{name.split('.')[0]}_{year}.{name.split('.')[1]}"

        # Rename the file
        os.rename(f, new_name)

How it works:
Splitting the Filename: The filename is split into two parts using the first underscore (_) as a delimiter. This helps to separate the year from the rest of the name.
Forming the New Filename: The year is appended to the end of the filename (after the first part), and the file extension is kept intact.
Renaming the File: The os.rename() function is used to rename the file with the new format.
Example:
For the file 2023_FamilyDrama.pdf, the script will rename it to FamilyDrama_2023.pdf. Similarly, 2024_FamilyDrama.pdf will become FamilyDrama_2024.pdf, and 2022-beachpics.pdf will become beachpics_2022.pdf.
Make sure to replace 'your_directory_path_here' with the actual path where your files are stored.

This will not work given the source filenames in the question

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
